# find_or_create_by in many to many

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Now I have 3 models

```
Membership:
    belongs_to :users
    belongs_to :groups

User: 
    has_many: groups, through: :memberships
    accepts_nested_attributes_for :groups
Group: 
    has_many: users, through: :memberships
```

Then I am doing

```
u1 = User.new(name: "u1")
u2 = User.new(name: "u2") 
g1 = Group.new(name: "1")
u1.groups.find_or_create_by g1.attributes
u2.groups.find_or_create_by g1.attributes
u1.save
u2.save
```

What I'd expect is

```
Groups.all.count == 1
```

But it's always got '2'.

How could I solve this problem?

Comment: this problem is specific to `has_many` with `through`. One solution is to add uniqueness validations on group and save it to db before assigning but that might suit your requirements.

Answer (score 0):

If you do the following only one group would be created

```
u1 = User.new(name: "u1")
u2 = User.new(name: "u2") 
g1 = Group.find_or_create_by_name(name: "1") #g1 is saved to db here
u1.groups << g1
u2.groups << g1
u1.save
u2.save

Group.all.count
# =>  1
```